# Using CloudFormation intrinsic functions when specifying 'userdata' script using a text file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, user-data, cloud-init

In CloudFormation I can use a built-in function !Sub to replace a variable inside a string with the value of a parameter:

```
Parameters:
  EnvironmentName:
    Type: String
    Default: Development

Resources:
  Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-0194c3e07668a7e36
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub
        - |
          #!/bin/bash
          ENV_NAME=${my_env}
          hostnamectl set-deployment $ENV_NAME
        - {
            my_env: !Ref EnvironmentName
          }
```

When I try to pass UserData script using a text file I get the following error:

```
util.py[WARNING]: Failed loading yaml blob. Invalid format at line 2 column 1: "could not determine a constructor for the tag '!Sub
```

Replacing !Sub with Fn::Sub: does not result in an error but the hostnamectl file remains unchanged.

My CF template:

```
Parameters:
  UserData:
    Type: String

Resources:
  Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-0194c3e07668a7e36
      UserData: !Ref UserData
```

My UserData file:

```
#cloud-config
!Sub
    - |
        #!/bin/bash
        ENV_NAME=${my_env}
        hostnamectl set-deployment $ENV_NAME
    - {
        my_env: !Ref EnvironmentName
        }
```

My create-stack CLI command:

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name my-stack \
        --template-body file://my-stack.yaml \
        --parameters ParameterKey=UserData,ParameterValue=$(base64 userdata.txt) ParameterKey=EnvironmentName,ParameterValue=Development
```

I wonder if there is a workaround to use CloudFormation intrinsic functions when 'userdata' is specified using a text file.

Comment: Can you include at least the resource from your CloudFormation template where you're including the UserData?

Comment: Can you show full template?

Comment: I restructured my question and included the template. I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a syntax error in your template. I've done something similar for installing the CodeDeploy agent. I've included it as an example below:

```yaml
UserData:
  Fn::Base64: !Sub |
    #!/bin/bash
    sudo yum -y update
    sudo yum -y install ruby wget
    cd /home/ec2-user
    wget https://aws-codedeploy-${AWS::Region}.s3.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/latest/install
    chmod +x ./install
    sudo ./install auto
```

So in your case, I'd simplify your code to:

```yaml
UserData:
  Fn::Base64: !Sub |
    #!/bin/bash
    ENV_NAME=${EnvironmentName}
    hostnamectl set-deployment $ENV_NAME
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Just to clarify, the first template, where I pass userdata script in-line is working for me and I use that approach to import values from other stacks. Now, I'd like to be able to pass the same UserData script using a text file but inclusion of the !Sub function in userdata.txt file seems to be causing an error.

Comment: Have you looked at [AWS Inlude transform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/create-reusable-transform-function-snippets-and-add-to-your-template-with-aws-include-transform.html)? It will only work with yaml and json and not with txt of course.